# Form select option selected PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, selected

I try to find the way how to make option tag selected if contain current day.

For example if my string `$currentDay=03;` called by PHP `date('d');` I would like my select like this:

```
<select>
<option value="01">01</option>
<option value="02">02</option>
<option value="03" selected>03</option>
<option value="04">04</option>
...
... 
</select>
```

Comment: `<option value="03" <?= $currentDay === '03' ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>03</option>`

Comment: if you use above method then use this line each and every statement

Comment: The if condition you gave in your question actually is the answer.

Comment: You build the `option`s dynamically or statically?

Comment: To elaborate a bit on the comment: `<?=` is shorthand for `<?php echo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php $day=date('d');?>
<select>
<option value="01" <?=($day=='01')?'selected':'';?> >01</option>
<option value="02" <?=($day=='02')?'selected':'';?> >02</option>
<option value="03" <?=($day=='03')?'selected':'';?> >03</option>
<option value="04" <?=($day=='04')?'selected':'';?> >04</option>
...
... 
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
$day = date('d');
$selected = ' selected="selected" ';
<select>
   <option value="01" <?php if($day=='01') echo $selected; ?>>01</option>
   <option value="02" <?php if($day=='02') echo $selected; ?>>02</option>
   <option value="03" <?php if($day=='03') echo $selected; ?>>03</option>
   <option value="04" <?php if($day=='04') echo $selected; ?>>04</option>
   ...
   ... 
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select>
    <? foreach ($options as $option) : ?>
        <option value="<?= $option ?>" <? if ($selected_option==$option) echo 'selected' ?>>
            <?= $option ?>
        </option>
    <? endforeach ?>
</select>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.